# Trying to run tests after a code change throws type loading exception in MsTest

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, mstest

After code changes when trying to run unit tests all tests fail with and error

> Unit Test Adapter threw exception:  Unable to load one or more of the
>   requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more
>   information..

If I just run them once under debugger, they all pass and until a change is done to "code under test" I can run them without any issue.
If I change the code I have to "debug" them first in order to run.

Using VS2010 SP1 under win7.

Any ideas how to get rid of this?

Comment: Can you please post some sample unit test code? Are you using the Visual Studio unit test system?

Comment: Yes, MsTest (see tag).

I do not think that posting code would be relevant as this happens to all tests. And are simple ones (create instance, set some parameters, assert).
It is more like VS/MsTest is trying to load something and for some reasons is not able (like not deploying all dlls). And in these cases I'm not dynamically loading stuff.